# Resource is not set?

Tags: adminhtml, magento-1.6, resource-model

I have created the custom tab in configuration and it is showing the form. when I import the file it is returning an error? **Resource is not set?**

can any one tell me where I went wrong?

my code is:

```
system.xml:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <newtab translate="label" module="mca">
            <label>New Tab</label>
            <sort_order>138</sort_order>
        </newtab>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
       <mca translate="label" module="mca">
            <label>New Test Section</label>
            <tab>newtab</tab>
            <sort_order>138</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <mca module="mca" translate="label">
                    <label>Test Group</label>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <test translate="label">
                            <label>My Name Is :</label>
                            <comment>My Custom Label</comment>
                            <tooltip>My Name Is :</tooltip>
                            <frontend_type>Text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </test>
                    </fields>
                    <fields>
                        <slider translate="label">
                            <label>My Method Arrays</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>mca/source</source_model>
                            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </slider>
                    </fields>
                    <fields>
                        <export translate="label">
                            <label>Export</label>
                            <frontend_type>export</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>mca/csv</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </export>
                    </fields>
                    <fields>
                        <import translate="label">
                            <label>Import</label>
                            <frontend_type>import</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>mca/import</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </import>
            </fields>            
                </mca>
            </groups>
        </mca>      
    </sections>

</config>

adminhtml.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mca translate="label" module="mca">
                                        <title>New Test Section</title>
                                        <sort_order>138</sort_order>
                                    </mca>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**Mca->Model->Import.php**

```
<?php


class Course_Mca_Model_Import extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->uploadAndImport($this);
    }


    public function uploadAndImport(Varien_Object $object)
    {
        if(isset($_FILES['import_file']['name']) && $_FILES['import_file']['name'] != '')
        {
            $uploaderFile = new Varien_File_Uploader('import_file');
            $uploaderFile->setAllowedExtensions(array());
            $uploaderFile->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            $uploaderFile->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $uploaderFilepath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'importcsv' . DS ;
            $uploaderFile->save($uploaderFilepath, $_FILES['import_file']['name'] );
            $file = $_FILES['import_file']['name'];
            $filepath = $uploaderFilepath.$file;
            $i = 0;
            if(($handle = fopen("$filepath", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
                    if($i>0 && count($data)>1){
                        updateData($data);
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            else{
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("There is some Error");
                $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
            }
        }
    }

    protected  function updateData($data)
    {
        //Write your code here and Update it to magento tables
    }

}
```

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please include your config.xml.

Comment: You want to import some data uploading file? Is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow magento standard way:
1.Change export field of your config:

```
<export translate="label">
    <label>Select file</label>
    <frontend_type>import</frontend_type>
    <backend_model>mca/adminhtml_system_config_backend_import</backend_model>
    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</export>
```

2.Your backend_model Course/Mca/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Backend/Import.php:

```
class Course_Mca_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Backend_Import extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    public function _afterSave()
    {
        $this->uploadAndImport($this);
    }

    public function uploadAndImport(Varien_Object $object)
    {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```